# Can hyperterminal from Windows write incoming data to a log file?

Tags: windows, hyperterminal

I use the standard hyperterminal from Windows.

Can this terminal write incoming data to a file automatically?

Also who can share such log file? Does it have a standard data format?

Answer (score 2):

#### Can hyperterminal from windows write incoming data to a log file?

Yes it can.

> Can this terminal write incoming data to a file automatically?

No it won't do this automatically. You could use a keyboard macro program to automate this.

> Also who can share such log file?

That depends on the permissions assigned to the log file.

> Does it have a standard data format?

The data is saved as a text file.

---

#### To save incoming data to a text file

> 1. Open HyperTerminal.
> 2. Connect to the remote computer using either a new connection or using an saved connection. Alternatively, you can wait for a call and
>      have the remote computer connect to your computer.
> 3. On the Transfer menu, click "Capture Text" or, to send the text file directly to a printer, click "Capture to Printer".
> 4. In the File box, type a descriptive name for the file, and then click "Start".
> 5. Any text typed at the remote computer will now be captured in the specified file, or be sent to the printer.
> 6. To stop capturing the text to a file, on the HyperTerminal Transfer menu click "Capture Text", then click "Stop" or "Pause".
> 7. To stop capturing the text to a printer, on the HyperTerminal Transfer menu click "Capture to Printer", which will uncheck this
>      selection.
>
> Notes:
>
> - Performing this task does not require you to have administrative credentials. Therefore, as a security best practice, consider
>     performing this task as a user without administrative credentials.
> - To open HyperTerminal, click Start, point to All programs, point to Accessories, point to Communications, and then click HyperTerminal.
> - HyperTerminal is not installed by default. For information on how to install HyperTerminal, see Related Topics.
> - When saving incoming data to a text file or sending the data to a printer, HyperTerminal will capture all data transmitted during the
>     connection session. You cannot use HyperTerminal to filter the data.

Source [Save incoming data to a text file](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc738294%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)